# graylog on shared hosting

Tags: php, apache, graylog

Is it possible to collect php log files from shared hosting? Some of my clients have a small hosting package without the possibility to install an apache module.

Importing the log data from FTP or related would be a good solutionl

Answer (score 1):

As long as you can fetch the raw log files, you can import them into Graylog using [Filebeat](https://www.elastic.co/products/beats/filebeat), [Logstash](https://www.elastic.co/products/logstash), or any other log shipper which supports a protocol supported by Graylog (such as GELF, Beats/Lumberjack or Syslog).